# how to replace my select with something else

Tags: javascript

hello for now I have a purchase order with 300 items in jquery
where I select the articles with a select

It works great, but I find it gives a bad user experience.

I wish I could override this select
with for example a plus and a minus to add and remove items

With this piece of code
here is how I operate to retrieve information

select information is retrieved in real time with onchange

the rest of the information is transmitted when I click on the "ajouter au panier" button

```
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                        <select class="form-select styleselect " id="2001" aria-label="2001" onchange="changeQte(this);">
                          <option selected value="1">1 sachet </option>
                          <option value="2">2 sachets</option>
                          <option value="3">3 sachets </option>
                          <option value="4">4 sachets </option>
                          <option value="5">5 sachets </option>
                          <option value="6">6 sachets </option>
                          <option value="7">7 sachets </option>
                          <option value="8">8 sachets </option>
                          <option value="9">9 sachets </option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      <a style="cursor: pointer; margin-bottom: 5px;width: 90%;display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;" data-nom="2001" data-prix="1.10" data-qte="1" data-checkbox="2001" data-url="https://phil.pecheperle.be/image-perles/perle-verre-peche-gardon-2001.JPG" class="btn btn-primary ajouter-panier b-items__item__add-to-cart" onclick="ouvreMaJolieAlert(event);">
                        ajouter au panier
                      </a>
```

Comment: So you have a list of items and instead of using a select dropdown you want to list all 300 on the page and then use +/- to add/remove items from a new list?

Comment: thank you for the answer
no, this is much simpler, I would like to be able to retrieve the id of the select first
then with a + and - button modify the value of the select

Comment: So if I select option 3 the +/- buttons would change "3 sachets" to "4 sachets" or "2 sachets", for example?

Comment: yes that's perfect you understand
the goal being to remove the select
I think it will be more intuitive for the user to click on + or - to obtain a quanditee

Comment: Why not just use an `<input>` with a "number" type? It's built-in. It doesn't have +/- buttons but it does have up/down arrows. `<input type="number" name="quantity" />`, for example. And if you don't want to use the arrows you can just enter a number instead.

Comment: it is elderly people who will place orders and risk not seeing these mini arrows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution might be to add the items in the purchase order to an array as a series of objects with `id`, `name`, and `qty` properties.

You can then iterate over this array to produce a list of items, each with their own +/- buttons. Clicking on the buttons will a) update the input box with an incremented/decremented value, and also update the `qty` value in the corresponding object in the array.

```js
// Array of objects each representing one item
// in your purchase order
const arr = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Potato', qty: 0 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Leek', qty: 0 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Tomato', qty: 0 },
  { id: 4, name: 'Pear', qty: 0 },
  { id: 5, name: 'Apple', qty: 0 },
];

// To create a list item for each object in the array
// `map` over the array, and generate some HTML using a
// template string. Inside each item are two buttons, and
// and input field. `join` the array into a single string
// once the iteration is complete.
const itemHTML = arr.map(obj => {
  return `
    <li data-id=${obj.id}>
      <span class="itemname">${obj.name}</span>
      <button data-type="subtract">-</button>
      <input size="3" max-size="3" value=${obj.qty} />
      <button data-type="add">+</button>
    </li>
  `;
}).join('');

// Cache the list and submit button elements
const list = document.querySelector('ul');
const submit = document.querySelector('.submit');

// Add listeners to the list and submit buttons elements
list.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
submit.addEventListener('click', handleSubmit);

// Add the itemHTML we generated to the list element
list.innerHTML = itemHTML;

// When the list element captures an event from one of
// its child elements
function handleClick(e) {

  // First check that it's a button
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {

    // Destructure the button's parent element (the list item
    // element), and its type from its dataset
    const { parentElement: item, dataset: { type } } = e.target;

    // Extract the id from the item's dataset,
    // and find its input field, and extract its value
    const { dataset: { id } } = item;
    const input = item.querySelector('input');
    const { value } = input;

    // If the button type is "subtract" and the input value
    // is greater than zero, update the input field value with
    // a decremented value
    if (type === 'subtract' && Number(value) > 0) {
      input.value = Number(value) - 1;
    }

    // If the button type is "add" and the input value
    // is less than 300, update the input field value with
    // an incremented value
    if (type === 'add' && Number(input.value) <= 300) {
      input.value = Number(value) + 1;
    }

    // Finally find the object in the array that has an
    // id that matches the item id, and update its qty value
    const obj = arr.find(obj => obj.id === Number(id));
    obj.qty = Number(input.value);

  }
}

// Clicking on the submit button will show the
// update array of objects
function handleSubmit() {
  console.log(arr);
}
```

```css
.container { display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; }
ul { list-style: none; margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0; border: 1px solid lightgray; padding: 0.5em; }
.itemname { display: inline-block; width: 50px; text-align: right; margin-right: 0.5em; }
li:not(:last-child) { margin-bottom: 0.5em; }
li input { text-align: center; height: 24px; }
li button { width: 30px; aspect-ratio: 1; }
li button, li input { font-size: 1em; }
.submit { font-size: 1em; margin-top: 0.25em; }
```

```html
<section class="container">
<ul></ul>
<button class="submit">Show purchase order</button>
</section>
```

Additional documentation

- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)

Comment: a very very big thank you for this code and the explanations it works wonderfully

Comment: Happy to help, @ariane. I added some links to documentation for some of the methods I used that you might not be familiar with to the end of the answer.